# Create migrations from database in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-7

Is there a way to create migrations from an existing database in Laravel 7. I tried several but they are not working with Laraval 7.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... "I tried several ...", tried several what? would you like to provide what you tried

Comment: Not natively, maybe there is a package.

Comment: There was a way for Laravel 5 https://laravel-news.com/export-from-mysql-workbench-to-a-laravel-migration You could give it a shot for L7. Assuming your project is of medium size, you could be better off by creating the migrations manually. Respect the natural order of the table hierarchy (foreign keys) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can generate migrations from an existing database in Laravel. Open source laravel packages have made it easier to do so.

For Laravel 7 Kitloong's Laravel migration generator is the best match for creating migrations from an existing database.

This is the github package -> https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator

In very basic and simple steps you will get the things you need. You just need to install the package.

```
composer require --dev "kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator"
```

After installation run :

```
php artisan migrate:generate
```

If you want to generate migrations for specific table :-

```
php artisan migrate:generate table1,table2,...,table_n
```

If you want to ignore some tables :

```
php artisan migrate:generate --ignore="table3,table4"
```

For full documentation you can visit -> https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator

Thanks to Kitloong's Laravel Migration Generator.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below command to migrate each table separately.

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/migrationnamefull.php
```

it will work.